# Open file and write to other file

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I need files and write their content to other file. Any ideas how to do it?

I tried the following, but it's not working, the output was only from 1 file not from all

```
$files = glob('texts/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file){
  $opn = fopen($file, "r");
  $rad = fread($opn, 1024000);
  fclose($opn);
  $opn = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
  fwrite($opn, $rad);
  fclose($opn);
}
```

Comment: How much data are we taliking - can you read all the content into memory than write it once?

Comment: I think your script should work. The only bug I see is if any of the input files is more than `1024000` bytes long, you won't get the whole file. But it should write them all to the output file.

Comment: I just tried your script, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
$filesss = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
if ($handle = opendir('./texts/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $obsah = file_get_contents('./texts/'.$entry);
            fwrite($filesss, $entry.$obsah.'
');
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
fclose($filesss);
```

Not be best solution, but for me just.
Thansk :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get content of the file by using [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and save the content in another file by using [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) 
So you can put below in your loop

```
$files = glob('texts/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file){
   // Open the file to get existing content
   $content = file_get_contents($file);
   // Write the contents to the new file
   file_put_contents('new_'.$file, $content);
}
```

If you want to merge all files content and put them in one file, you can change it as

```
$files = glob('texts/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
$content = ''
foreach($files as $file){
   // Open the file to get existing content
   $content. = file_get_contents($file);
}
// Write the contents to the new file
file_put_contents('output.txt', $content);
```

Comment: You will need the `FILE_APPEND` flag since he wants all files to be combined into 1 new file `output.txt`.

Comment: @AzizSaleh but I think he wants each file in a separate file (he says "*but it's not working, the output was only from 1 file not from all*")

Comment: Yes, I need texts friom all files to 1 file, but your code not working :(

Comment: @Johner What's your OS? *The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non GNU systems, like Solaris.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php5 or up use [File_put_contents](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and loop it

e.g.

```
 int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about that (and it would be interesting to know if you get errors in this regard) but it is possible that the release time of the output file is not fast enough to allow you to reopen it from the second iteration on...

Try with something like this and see if it works:

```
$files = glob('texts/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
$output = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
foreach($files as $file){
    $opn = fopen($file, "r");
    $rad = fread($opn, 1024000);
    fclose($opn);
    fwrite($output, $rad);
}
fclose($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have execution privileges, this can be faster (If you are on Linux):

```
$files = glob('texts/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file){
    exec("cat $file >> output.txt");
}
```

Without the loop:

```
exec("cat texts/*.txt >> output.txt");
```